# How to read mount files with pyreadstat read_xport function in Databricks?

Tags: python, azure-databricks

Mounted the xpt file from Azure storage to the Databricks DBFS path. With pyreadstat read_xport getting the below error even though test.xpt file exists in the mount path folder.

Can anyone please let me know how to access the .xpt file with/without mounting with pyreadstat read_xport function?

```
mount_file_path = f"/dbfs/mnt/test.xpt"

df_xpt, xpt_meta = pyreadstat.read_xport(mount_file_path)

PyreadstatError: File /dbfs/mnt/test.xpt does not exist!
```

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results**

I created a sample data frame and saved the same Dataframe `df`  into the `/dbfs/demo.xpt` location using the write operation.

Make sure to install **pyreadstat**, you can  use this command for installing **pyreadstat** package:`pip install pyreadstat`.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2.0,"A"],[3,4.0,"B"]], columns=["k1", "k2", "k3"]
column_labels = ["Var 1", "Var 2", "Var 3"]
pyreadstat.write_xport(df, "/dbfs/demo.xpt", file_label="test", column_labels=column_labels)
```

Successfully access .XPT file using below command:

```
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_xport('/dbfs/demo.xpt', metadataonly=True)
```

Now you can check ,

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to copy the **xpt** file from *Azure storage* to **dbfs**, Please follow below code:

```
#Set Blob storage configuration
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.vamblob.blob.core.windows.net","<access_key>")
```

#Use this command to copy the **xpt** file from *Azure storage* to **dbfs**

```
dbutils.fs.cp("wasbs://pool@vamblob.blob.core.windows.net/<file_name>.xpt","dbfs:/<your_file_name>")
```

[image]

Comment: @ SaiVamsi - Thanks for looking into this. If we write  xpt file to dataframe and then write to the xpt file some of the data may be incorrect due to the datatype mismatch. To avoid that want to load as-is data from the data source file. Even though file is there in the mount path with pyreadstat not able to locate the file, instead of mounting can you please let me know how to copy the xpt file from Azure storage to dbfs, so that it will be easy to read.

Comment: Hi @skp, please check the above update.

Comment: @ SaiVamsi - Awesome!! Thanks again. It's working. Mount is also working now. earlier in the mount configs used "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "CustomAccessToken" instead of "fs.azure.account.auth.type":"OAuth"